# How to select a set of records where a column value is the same in all results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a query, limited by a specified # of seats, that selects a group of seats from a seat map that is divided into sections.

It attempts to grab all of the needed seats from the same section, but if that section doesn't have enough seats to satisfy the requested quantity, it grabs the remaining seats from the next section.

No good.

While I can probably figure out a convoluted way in PHP to take my result set, check for more than one section, and if so, skip the first few available seats in the section that doesn't have enough quantity available, and re-query again to ensure I get all of my needed seats in the next section.

Whew! Messy.

However, I'd like to figure this out in SQL. Code below.

```
SELECT et.id, et.event_id, et.seat_id, et.zone_id, s.seat_number, r.row_name, r.row_priority, sc.section_name, sc.section_priority, z.zone_name, s.seat_handicap, s.seat_obstructed, ticket_base_price, yth_boxoffice_ticket_fee, yth_online_ticket_fee, vendor_boxoffice_ticket_fee, vendor_online_ticket_fee 
FROM yth_event_tickets et
LEFT JOIN yth_seats s ON et.seat_id = s.id
RIGHT JOIN yth_seatmap_rows r ON s.seat_row_id = r.id
RIGHT JOIN yth_seatmap_sections sc ON r.row_section_id = sc.id
RIGHT JOIN yth_seatmap_zones z ON sc.section_zone_id = z.id
WHERE event_id = 101252413
AND zone_id = 1
AND ticket_status = 1
AND s.seat_active = 1
ORDER BY r.row_priority ASC, sc.section_priority ASC, s.seat_priority ASC
LIMIT 4
```

I order by Row first, then Section. That way, it goes around the stadium and grabs the first Row from each Section first, and when those are filled, starts in Row 2, and so forth, so that it selects "best available" back.

As you can see, I only want 4 seats. I get 2 seats in Section B, but then Section B is full, so I get the remaining 2 seats from Section C. What I'd like to be able to do is skip over those last 2 seats in Section B and get my 4 seats in Section C. Furthermore, if Section C only has, say, < 4 remaining seats, and skip it as well and move on to Section D, etc...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, count the number of available seats per section (or per zone, section, row - whatever you need), something like:

```
SELECT se.id, COUNT(*) AS seats_available
  FROM yth_seats s
  JOIN yth_rows r
    ON s.row_id = r.id
  JOIN yth_sections se
    ON se.id = r.section_id
 WHERE status = 1
 GROUP BY se.id
```

With that, you can join that information back to your main query, limiting your results just to the section that has enough seats:

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM (SELECT se.id, COUNT(*) AS seats_available
          FROM yth_seats s
          JOIN yth_rows r
            ON s.row_id = r.id
          JOIN yth_sections se
            ON se.id = r.section_id
         WHERE STATUS = 1
         GROUP BY se.id) section_available
  JOIN yth_sections se
    ON se.id = section_available.id
  JOIN yth_rows r
    ON r.section_id = se.id
  JOIN yth_seats s
    ON s.row_id = r.id
 WHERE s.status = 1
   AND section_available.seats_available >= 4
 -- your priorities
 ORDER BY se.NAME
 LIMIT 4
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=499599a3280d2239260db80a7645f9db)

You didn't mention which version of MySQL you're using, I'd normally go with a CTE instead of a subquery, but this feature might not yet be available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback (sorry for the tardiness  in replying). A modified version of this subquery on grabbing the sections with enough seats to satisfy the requested quantity is working. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you requiring all seats to be on the same row, or just in the same zone?
I'm supposing in the same row.

I'm not going to try to understand all your tables, so I'll imagine you have a view of  seats:

zone,rowno,seatno

```sql
;WITH avail AS (SELECT TOP 1 zone,rowno FROM seats -- find the first row with 4 or more seats
GROUP BY zone,rowno
HAVING COUNT(*) >=4
ORDER BY zone,rowno)
-- select the first 4 seats from that row.
SELECT top 4 seats.* FROM avail INNER JOIN seats
ON avail.zone = seats.zone AND avail.rowno=seats.rowno
ORDER BY seatno
```